# What is 'valid signal' that router receives to indicate physical status is 'up'?

Tags: ethernet

> If the Ethernet interface has a cable connected and is receiving a valid signal, the physical link shows an “up” status and there are no active alarms or defects. If the interface is not connected or is not receiving a valid signal, the output shows a physical link down status and an active LINK alarm and defect.

Source: http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB26486

What is that 'valid signal'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Link Integrity Test pulses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonegotiation#Electrical_signals).

> They are unipolar positive-only electrical pulses of a nominal duration of 100 ns, with a maximum pulse width of 200 ns, generated at a 16 ms time interval (with a timing variation tolerance of 8 ms).
>
> [...]
>
> A device detects the failure of a link if neither a frame nor two of the LIT pulses is received for 50-150 ms.

Comment: Thanks. On router fastethernet interface with status 'link=up, protocol=down' without any cable attached on the interface, how come 'link=up'?

Comment: Sounds fishy. Maybe a broken MAC.